# Escape quotes in comma separated string JSON

Tags: json

In my json data I need a string value to be inside double quotes
like this:

```
NAME: " \" Aya Ali, John Smith\" ",
```

so the result should be "Aya Ali, John Smith"

but I get: Aya Ali, John Smith"

I guess because there's a comma inside a string and json treats it as two separate values. What should be the way to keep the comma inside the string but still get the quotes from both sides?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Basically, I would suggest using a JSON library and let that get it right - but at the moment we don't know what language you're using, whether or not you're using a library at all, or what your code looks like - which makes it very hard to help any further. Please could you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

Your example is valid JSON, so if you're having trouble, it depends what language you are using when working with the JSON.

Your example works fine in Javascript for example.  (There's a space between the first quote and Aya which may or may not have been intended)

In PHP, it is handy to use json_encode() like this:

```
echo json_encode(array('NAME'=>'"Aya Ali, John Smith"'));
```

Which will return:

```
{"NAME":"\"Aya Ali, John Smith\""}
```